# VMWare slowly freezing whole system

Tags: vmware, freeze, vmware-player, uptime

Background:

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS and running Win 10 as guest for random MS specific apps OS on VMWare Workstation 15 Player. Everything appears to work really smooth and nice... for a while. After system has been up for a week or two, weird things start to happen.

At some point, I see various desktop features freezing/unresponsive, and by digging what's going on, it always seems to somehow point to vmware-vmx process. I.e. when I run simple `ps aux` at terminal, it gets frozen when printing details fof vmware-vmx. By doing `strace ps aux` I can see that it always gets stuck when reading from /proc/vmware-vmx-PID/cmdline file. The `ps aux` is frozen so hard that it can't be killed.

[image: strace ps aux screenshot]

Also killing the vmware-vmx process doesn't seem to fix the problem. After killing the process, system continues to behave weird and cause lots of lock-ups with many apps. Only reboot seems to recover from it (or actually hard-reset, because reboot also gets stuck waiting to shutdown *snapd* daemon forever).

What is most terrifying is that doing the system reboot at that state has tendency to corrupt files that I assume some apps are trying to write when closing. On next boot I see some files being empty (i.e. thunderbird passwords were once lost, another time eclipse workspace settings were lost because it contained an empty file, vmware disk image was crapped also once).

**Any idea what's going on here? 
OR any positive experiences with vmware with long uptimes?**

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Sys specs:

- VMWare Workstation 15 Player 15.0.2
- 64 bit kernel 4.15.0-44
- Core i5-6600
- 24 GB RAM, memtest86 pass
- Geforce 1060 with NVidia drivers 410.78 (390.xx also tried, no difference)
- KDE 5
- Ubuntu updates up to date
- **System *should* be stable, it's been used for 3 years on Win7 without stability issues (uptime several months between boots & active use, no problems)**

Comment: As an experiment I have ran VMWare without 3D acceleration enabled and no stability issue occurred during 24 day uptime. Perhaps the freezing is related to VMware's 3D support OR nvidia drivers. Next test is to try with other display drivers/GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back the kernel to 4.15.0-43 (or -42). There's known issues around external displays (though I've had the same lock-up symptoms you described the last two days). My kernel updated to 4.15.0-44 yesterday (check with `grep 4.15.0-44 /var/log/dpkg.log`). I suggest installing ukuu to manage kernels.

I'm also running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64 bit on an i7-8850h, 32 GB RAM.

Links:

- [Redit link about the kernel bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/albov8/ubuntu_1804_black_screen_problem_with_external/?ref=readnext)
- [Ukuu Kernal Manager - FOSS Mint](https://www.fossmint.com/ukuu-install-and-upgrade-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks for hint! However I'm not certain that these kernel version would solve this. The lockups have been haunting me since I installed Ubuntu, over two months ago, and it has gone thru few kernel versions on that time. All of them had same issue.